# How to validate two fields that depend on each other with Yup. If one is not empty, then ask to enter other as well

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

I have following yup validator. I want either one is fill up the data, another one must be required.

If user enter termination_date, then reason_for_termination must be required.
If user enter reason_for_termination, then termination_date must be required.
If both are empty, it is valid.

I want I got javascript error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: branch is not a function
    at _Condition.fn (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:418:51)
    at _Condition.resolve (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:432:23)
    at yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:819:71
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _DateSchema.resolve (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:819:27)
    at ObjectSchema._cast (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:1908:23)
    at ObjectSchema.cast (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:842:33)
    at yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:2174:42
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at ArraySchema._cast (yup.js?v=ec75f2a1:2173:29)
```

yup validator.

```
const agentHistorySchema = yup.object().shape(
  {

    termination_date: yup.date().when("reason_for_termination", {
      is: (reason_for_termination) =>
        reason_for_termination && reason_for_termination.length > 0,
      then: yup.date().required("Please enter termination_date as well"),
      otherwise: yup.date(),
    }),
    reason_for_termination: yup.string().when("termination_date", {
      is: (termination_date) => termination_date && termination_date.length > 0,
      then: yup
        .string()
        .required("Please enter reason_for_termination as well"),
      otherwise: yup.string(),
    }),
  },
  [["termination_date", "reason_for_termination"]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there might be a syntax error in your usage of `when` with the `object().shape` method in the Yup schema. The error, "TypeError: branch is not a function," usually indicates that there is an issue with the structure of the schema.

```js
const agentHistorySchema = yup.object().shape({
  termination_date: yup.date().when("reason_for_termination", 
      is: (reason_for_termination) => reason_for_termination && reason_for_termination.length > 0,
        then: yup.date().required("Please enter termination_date as well"),
        otherwise: yup.date(),
      }),
  reason_for_termination: yup.string().when("termination_date", {
        is: (termination_date) => termination_date && termination_date.length > 0,
        then: yup.string().required("Please enter reason_for_termination as well"),
        otherwise: yup.string(),
      }),
    });
```

I removed the extra array, `["termination_date", "reason_for_termination"]`, at the end, as it's not necessary for the shape method.